# How do i use the top keyword in an insert statement?

Tags: sql-server

I was using it as LIMIT when I got the exception `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'`.

Maybe I can omit it in this case without a problem, but if I couldn't where do I put top?

```
INSERT INTO [user_data] (...) SELECT 
...
@14 WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM [user_data] WHERE [email] = @15 OR 
[name] = @16 OR 
[unconfirmed_email] = @17 TOP 1);
```

Comment: This sadly is the most non standard feature in SQL, I sure hope some later standard chooses and sticks with a single method.  I keep this link handy when I jump databases

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm

Comment: @blissapp nice link, +1 - and in the body it doesn't even get to mentioning yet another non-standard way of doing it for DB2 (it's mentioned in the comments though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TOP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) goes after `SELECT` in SQL Server, not like where `LIMIT` goes in other DBMSes.

`SELECT TOP 1 <fields> FROM ...`

So your query would become:

```
INSERT INTO [user_data] (...) SELECT
...
@14 WHERE not exists (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [user_data] WHERE [email] = @15 OR 
[name] = @16 OR 
[unconfirmed_email] = @17);
```